# Rundeck - flow execution with error handler

Tags: rundeck

Default error handler works in a way, if any job sequence does not end with the non-zero status it went into error handler flow.

I wanted to implement the flow, if the API endpoint returns 204, I need to perform some dependent operation.

I was thinking of doing it using an error handler but how I can deal with the return status 204 as it just handles non-zero status flow in the error handler.

Answer (score 0):

On Rundeck Enterprise you can do it using the Ruleset Strategy (for example, catch the exit code and put it on a data option to decides if runs or not another job), take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/workflow-strategies/ruleset.html#ruleset-workflow-strategy-plugin).

On the Community version you can do it scripting, manage the behavior on an script step in the following way (on my example i want to detect only the 127 error, defined on an option):

A job definition example:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='code_to_catch' value='127' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>ab58e8e3-78f8-4a60-b6fc-4ad1167aa3a4</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[date-foo-bar # intentional error
mycode=$(printf '%d\n' $?)

case $mycode in
@option.code_to_catch@)
  echo "Executing actions for @option.code_to_catch@ error"
  ## also, you can run any job using RD-CLI (https://rundeck.github.io/rundeck-cli/) 
  ## or Rundeck API (https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html)
  ;;
0)
  echo "all ok!"
  exit 0
  ;;
esac

]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>ab58e8e3-78f8-4a60-b6fc-4ad1167aa3a4</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

As you see, you can use the inline script to caught the error code and later run another job using [RD-CLI](https://rundeck.github.io/rundeck-cli/) if you like.

Comment: I have rundeck enterprise but did not properly understand how to capture the return code from the last reference job, I understand that we have "result.resultCode" as well as "execution.status" but both ruleset rules is not working for me.

Comment: Hi! For Rundeck Enterprise-related questions please contact the dedicated support team, they will help you ASAP :-)